# In windows Universal application (UWP) "global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break()" Error Generate when use Tab and Alter Tab

Tags: xaml, windows-10, uwp, visual-studio-2015

I am working on windows universal app,In this app when i use tab and alter + tab then ,the application automatically terminate and show this error .I just captured a picture so you can see.

Error Image:[image: Exception Occur in Visual studio]

[image: After the application stopped]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This type of error is due to some logical error, resulting in the object having a null value. The main cause of this is when a Combobox does not get an index, causing the app to crash. Sometimes the XAML code can cause this but does not detect or inform you about the error.

Comment: I got this error due to incorrect XAML. I was experimenting with using Width="*" on a StackPanel.

Answer (score 0):

I was going left and right until i realized that GridView do not take Dictionary
cs:

```
public Dictionary<string , Folder> Files = new Dictionary<string , obj>();
```

xaml:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Files}">
```

=> error
fix:

```
<GridView ItemsSource="{x:Bind Files.Values}">
```